# Specific layout on UL for images

Tags: css, html-lists

How to code a ul list with images in order to look like the image below?

I guess I have to make something like this? (it's not the proper code)

```
<ul>
<li><ul><li>IMAGE1</li><li>IMAGE2</li></ul></li>
<li>IMAGE3</li>
</ul>
```

[image]

Comment: I am not sure this is an appropriate use of `ul`.

Answer (score 1):

[Use flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```
<ul style="list-style-type: none; flex-direction: row; display: flex; justify-content; center; align-items: center;">
  <li>
    <ul style="list-style-type: none; flex-direction: column; display: flex; justify-content; center; align-items: center;">
     <li>IMAGE1</li>
     <li>IMAGE2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>IMAGE3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I used UL because I can change the layout easily I guess - especially when I have to deal with different screens. Thanks for your help though. :)

Comment: UL is for bulletpoint lists, is that really what you want?

If this answer is useful, upvote it; if not, why not?

Comment: You can use UL for everything. I use UL lists for image galleries because it's easier to manipulate each element with CSS and the overall layout in order to look good in different screen sizes.